# How to connect to FTP server from android?

Tags: c#, java, android, ftp

I would like to programmatically add a Text document containing some information to my Windows FTP server from my android program. How would I go about doing this ? I am pretty new to network programming and Android in general, so if anyone can give me a step by step guide or point me to one would be very helpful. Thanks !

Comment: use commons net http://lavalatwork.blogspot.tw/2010/09/using-apache-commons-ftp-library-in.html

Comment: @qrtt1: Your comment should be changed to answer. I think it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ftp client library. In java, Commons Net library support ftp client, please see the blog post: [Using apache commons Ftp library in Android](http://lavalatwork.blogspot.tw/2010/09/using-apache-commons-ftp-library-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done that yet, but you can try/check

java.net.URLCOnnection and java.net.URL, which support FTP as well

Answer (score 0):

Another one that you can use is ftp4j (http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php)

Here is an example:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(serverName);
ftpClient.login(username, password);
ftpClient.setPassive(true);
ftpClient.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
final FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.list();
```